# Getting Import/Library issue in my robotframework

Tags: python, python-3.x, robotframework

Getting Import/Library issues in my robot framework, I've Customlib file where all my custom functions reside while trying to import the Customlib getting an error
[enter image description here][1]
[enter image description here][2]

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/poPzQ.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkbxK.png

CustomLib Code:
```

robot is complaining Setup failed: No keyword with name Customlib.get config test data

```
import os

# Declaring empty list for test data and config file
testData = {}
configTestData = {}


class CustomLib:
    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'Test Case'

    # Function for getting data from confi file and test data file altogether
    @staticmethod
    def get_global_config_data_and_test_data(testdata_filename):
        configpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        print(configpath)
        configpath1 = configpath.replace("Utils", "")
        configpath = configpath1.replace(configpath1, "config.properties")
        #        configpath=configpath.replace("Utils", "config.properties")
        try:
            file = open(configpath)
            for line in file:
                content = line.split("=")
                firstArgument = content[0]
                secondArgument = content[1]
                a = firstArgument.rstrip('\n')
                b = secondArgument.rstrip('\n')
                testData[a] = b
        except Exception as e:
            if hasattr(e, 'message'):
                print(e.message)
            else:
                print(e)
        finally:
            file.close()
        return CustomLib.get_testData_From_PropertiesFile(CustomLib.OS_path_fromat_separator(testdata_filename))

    # Function for reading test data from property file
    @staticmethod
    def get_testData_From_PropertiesFile(propfile):
        try:
            file = open(propfile)
            for line in file:
                content = line.split("=")
                firstArgument = content[0]
                secondArgument = content[1]
                a = firstArgument.rstrip('\n')
                b = secondArgument.rstrip('\n')
                testData[a] = b
        except Exception as e:
            if hasattr(e, 'message'):
                print(e.message)
            else:
                print(e)
        finally:
            file.close()
            return testData

    # FUnction for generating dynamic path which has text in XPATH
    def generate_dynamic_xpath(self, locatorvalue, replacement):
        after_replacement = locatorvalue.replace('#', replacement)
        return after_replacement

    # Function for creating report name
    def create_report_name(self, testContent, date):
        reportname = testContent.replace('date', date)
        return reportname

    # Function for reading config.properties file
    @staticmethod
    def get_config_testdata():
        configpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        print(configpath)
        configpath1 = configpath.replace("Utils", "")
        configpath = configpath1.replace(configpath1, "config.properties")
        #       configpath=configpath.replace("Utils", "config.properties")
        print(configpath)

        try:
            file = open(configpath)
            for line in file:
                content = line.split("=")
                firstArgument = content[0]
                secondArgument = content[1]
                a = firstArgument.rstrip('\n')
                b = secondArgument.rstrip('\n')
                configTestData[a] = b
        except Exception as e:
            if hasattr(e, 'Exception occured while reading properties file'):
                print(e.message)
            else:
                print(e)
        finally:
            file.close()
            return configTestData

    # Function to format the path for different OS
    @staticmethod
    def OS_path_fromat_separator(pathformat):
        config_data = {}
        config_data = CustomLib.get_config_testdata()
        if (config_data['OS'] == 'Windows'):
            OSPath = pathformat.replace('$', '//')
            return OSPath
        else:
            OSPath = pathformat.replace('$', '/')
            return OSPath

    # Function for generating dynamic CSS on the basis of text
    def generate_dynamic_CSS(self, locatorvalue, replacement):
        after_replacement = locatorvalue.replace('@', replacement)
        return after_replacement


def main():
    CustomLib.get_global_config_data()
    # CustomLib.get_testData_From_PropertiesFile()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Add your code as code, So that we can easily find out the issue and also we can edit if required. Please don't add code as image

Comment: @ManishKumar Added the code

Answer (score 0):

I'm using relative path to import custom library. Below is the reference, how to use import using relative path. So this should work.

```
Library             ..${/}foldername${/}customlibrary.py
```

And you can also use full path and import the library

Comment: I fixed that Import issue now robot is complaining 'Setup failed:
No keyword with name 'CustomLib.get config testdata' found." not sure what went wrong.

Comment: @Amengji How you are using this keyword from the test case? May be you can share your .robot file or part of the test case for clarity.